# Unlocking a Panel in visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using a panel in my desktop applications. The panel in the application is locked. I have tried to unlock the panel by clicking on lock controls but no solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Lock and UnLock properties of that control. And set the values according to your requirement.

Comment: The properties are disabled for the panel

Comment: Does this panel has some other parent control ?

Comment: Sorry i did'nt understand  "parent control?".How to verify this?

Comment: Does this panel that you adding is on another control other than Form ?
Just do one more thing. Go to  Format menu and choose a Lock Controls. And see If your control is present over there. If yes then unlock it from there.

Comment: No other control is there.panel is in the form directly,and the panel consists of two buttons